# Regex. Check if a specific character is present in a group of N characters

Tags: regex, match

The alphabet is `{0,1}`. I want to know if a 5 length token has at least a 1. So if I have this string `000000001`, the match should be `00001`.

Comment: Do you use a specific pattern matching library or are you asking for a formal regular expression?

Comment: What's the question?  Are you asking for help devising a regex?  If so, then what regex dialect do you need to use?

Comment: Formal regular expression.

Comment: That's a bit ambiguous, but I suppose you mean that you have only alternation, concatenation, grouping, and the `*` operator to work with.

Comment: I need the idea. I will figure it out how to use it for my problem.

Comment: Can your input have anything other than zeros and ones in it?

Comment: What would be the match for `000011000000`?  All of these can be found in it: `00001`, `00110`, `10000`.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller only 0 and 1. The match for `000011000000` would be `00001` and `10000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the brute force solution:

```
( 1 (0|1) (0|1) (0|1) (0|1) ) | ( (0|1) 1 (0|1) (0|1) (0|1) ) | ( (0|1) (0|1) 1 (0|1) (0|1) ) | ( (0|1) (0|1) (0|1) 1 (0|1) ) | ( (0|1) (0|1) (0|1) (0|1) 1 )
```

Without spaces:

```
(1(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1))|((0|1)1(0|1)(0|1)(0|1))|((0|1)(0|1)1(0|1)(0|1))|((0|1)(0|1)(0|1)1(0|1))|((0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
(1 (0|1) (0|1) (0|1) (0|1)) | (0 1 (0|1) (0|1) (0|1))  | (0 0 1 (0|1) (0|1)) | (0 0 0 1 (0|1)) | (0 0 0 0 1)
```

I'm pretty sure you can't do better (in the sense of using fewer non-whitespace symbols).  And since we are apparently being persnickety about whitespace, here it is without any:

```
(1(0|1)(0|1)(0|1)(0|1))|(01(0|1)(0|1)(0|1))|(001(0|1)(0|1))|(0001(0|1))|(00001)
```

Comment: `(0|1)` is written more easily as `[01]`.  For Four of them it would be [01]{4}, so you could simplify to `(1[01]{4})|(01[01]{3})|(001[01]{2})|(0001[01])|00001`

Comment: @StephenOstermiller character classes are not part of the regex formalism that the question asks to be used.  Nor quantifiers other than `*`.